# SQL Select to display one to one, one to many from many to many relation

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I'm trying to figure out SQL query that will list only one to one relation from below table.

Below Table contain 10 record where 8 are many to many relation data and 2 are one to one relation. Request your help with SQL that I can use to query below table and list out 2 records that has one to one relation.
Note: Table support many to many relation.

Table1:

```
Field1  Field2  
1       a   
2       a   
3       b   
4       b   
5       c       One to One
4       d
6       d   
6       e   
7       f   
7       j   
8       g       One to One
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WngtV.png)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by field1) as cnt1,
             count(*) over (partition by field2) as cnt2
      from t
     ) t
where cnt1 = 1 and cnt2 = 1;
```

You can also use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from t t2
                  where t2.field1 = t.field1 and t2.field2 <> t.field2
                 ) and      
      not exists (select 1 
                  from t t2
                  where t2.field2 = t.field2 and t2.field1 <> t.field1
                 ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful and worked well. Additional to that i also I want to list out one to many records i.e. record where field1 is  7, I tried tweaking the query but wasn't able to achieve the result. Could you please suggest select t.* from (select t.*, count() over (partition by field1) as cnt1, count() over (partition by field2) as cnt2 from t ) t where cnt1 > 1 and cnt2 = 1;

Comment: @Ellis2642 . . . I think you should ask a new question.